# Date compare and difference

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I have "Employee" table with employees' "StartDate".

I want to get a list of all employees who are reaching their work anniversary next month.

So far I have reached up to this point:

```
SELECT *
FROM Employee
WHERE DATEDIFF(DAY, DAY(StartDate), DAY(GETDATE())) = 30
```

...but this doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: What anniversary?

Comment: Thats only going to work for a single day? Is that what you want?

Comment: You've overused the `day` function. `datediff` works on dates, not days.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to get a list of all employees who are reaching their work anniversary next month.

first you find the next month date

```
DATEADD(MONTH, 1, GETDATE())
```

then you find the Employee whose `StartDate` is next month

```
SELECT *
FROM   Employee
WHERE  DATEPART(MONTH, StartDate) = DATEPART(MONTH, DATEADD(MONTH, 1, GETDATE()))
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will work functionally. The functions in the where clause might cause issues on large data sets though:

```
declare     @day int = day(getdate())
            ,@month int = month(getdate())

if @month = 12 set @month = 1
else set @month = @month +1

SELECT 
    [columns]
  FROM [table]
where day(Startdate) = @day
and MONTH(Startdate) = @month
```

Or if you don't care about the day (I think you probably don't) then:

```
declare @month int = month(getdate())

if @month = 12 set @month = 1
else set @month = @month +1

SELECT 
    [columns]
  FROM [table]
and MONTH(Startdate) = @month
```